# Exit Observable.zip in rxjava based on condition

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

In RXJava, I have a 2 observables which are responses from 2 downstream calls.One downstream call is a long poll call, other is a short one and returns right away.
I am using the Observable.zip to combine the responses of both the responses.The below code works fine.

```
Observable
 .zip(observable1, observable2)
 .flatMap(update -> foo(update));
```

Now what I want to implement is that if the output of the short downstream call (observable1) does not content a specific value, then skip the zip i.e dont wait for the output of the longer downstream call (observable2).
I tried to implement it in the below way, but if the condition is true it doesn't zip with the observable2, but it does not even emit observable1 response.

```
Observable finalresponse = observable1
                .takeWhile(obsResponse1 ->  checkIfValueExist(obsResponse1))
                .zipWith(observable2,  (observable1, observable2) -> execute(observable1, observable2))
                .flatMap(update -> main.execute(update));
```

Comment: why u making parallel call? Why not first make a call to downstream call which is the shortest, check the value and based on that make the long call

Comment: These are just two of the several calls that area made. For optimization I cant have these serial.

Comment: In your case, sequential calls will be more performant as u will not occupy memory for the second call at the very first place.

Answer (score 0):

In zip there is a rule it will return only if both of streams will emit an item so what you need to do is to filter or return Observable.empty() in observable if your object is not what you expect or you can use filter

```
   Observable
            .zip(Observable.just(1).filter(integer -> integer==1), Observable.just(2).filter(integer -> integer==3),(integer, integer2) -> integer)
            .flatMap(update -> foo(update));
```

Comment: What i did is below. But somehow the if the first checkIfValueExist returns false, the control of execution seems to be stuck and what i feel is waiting for 2nd response. 
`Observable finalresponse = Observable
                .zip(observable1.filter(obs1rep->  checkIfValueExist(obs1rep))), observable2,  (obs1, obs2) -> execute(obs1, obs2))
                .flatMap(update -> main.execute(update));`

Comment: if you want to dispose the stream try to use Observable.error() and if the result is false it will automatically stop the stream